# setup different testpath in pytest.ini

Tags: python, pytest

Is there any way I can setup different testpath under pytest.init for my test. so I can executing something like
**pytest xx** then all testcase can be executing from one set of multiple directies
**pytest yy** then all testcase can be executing from another set of multiple directies
**pytest all** then all testcase can be executing

so far I have. one set of test under unitA, unitB, unitC directies and another set of test under regressionA, regressionB, regressionC. so I do not need to type in
pytest unitA, unitB, unitC
pytest regressionA, regressionB, regressionC

my pytest.ini.

```
[pytest]
testpaths = unitA unitB
```

Answer (score 2):

Testpaths can be passed to `pytest` as positional arguments. If you are on *nix, you can use shell glob expansion to match multiple directories: `pytest unit*` will be expanded to `pytest unitA unitB unitC`. Similarly, `pytest unit{A,C}` will be expanded to `pytest unitA unitC`.

However, you can also define own arguments if you need custom test filtering or grouping logic. Example for a switch `--unit-only` that will run only tests in directories starting with `unit`, ignoring the `testpaths` setting in `pytest.ini`:

```python
# conftest.py
import pathlib
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--unit-only', action='store_true', default=False, help='only run tests in dirs starting with "unit".')


def pytest_configure(config):
    unit_only = config.getoption('--unit-only')
    if unit_only:
        config.args = [p for p in pathlib.Path().rglob('unit*') if p.is_dir()]
```